# How to pass values to a function with LinkedList<String> inline?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a simple function like:

```
private void function(LinkedList<String> a, LinkedList<String> b)
```

We already know that if those arguments were only string, passing values inline would be easy, like:

```
function("aaa", "bbb")
```

But is there a way to pass inline a LinkedList?

I tried with:

```
function(["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "B"])
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the type from `LinkedList` to the `List` interface, and then you can use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) like

```
function(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"), Arrays.asList("A", "B"))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to do it, but I'm not sure they will be clearer/shorter than the non-inline ways.

For example, using `Stream` API :

```
function (Stream.of("A","B","C").collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)),
          Stream.of("A","B").collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)));
```

You could use `Array.asList` if you don't need a specific `List` implementation (such as `LinkedList`) and don't mind the resulting `List` being fixed sized.

Or you can use `Array.asList` and still get a `LinkedList` :

```
function(new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")), 
         new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B")));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, without using any framework, but spoiler alert, it does not look any good to me:

```
function((LinkedList<String>) Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"),
        (LinkedList<String>) Arrays.asList("A", "B"));
```

If you are using the LinkedList just to concatenate the strings, then you could use StringBuilder, that could do the job and looks much better:

```
public void doSomething() {
    function(new StringBuilder()
            .append("A")
            .append("B")
            .append("C"), 
        new StringBuilder()
            .append("A")
            .append("B"));
}

private void function(StringBuilder a, StringBuilder b) { ... }
```

Cheer, Nikolas